# ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I am trying to create a spark dataframe so that I can insert data into a  already defined schema SQL database.

```
data=[{'Media': 'Twitter','Social Id':screen_name,
                   'Subscriber Name':name,
                  'Subscriber Location':location,'Latitude':latitude,'Longitude':longitude,'Comment':comment,'Bank Name':comp,
                   'Friends(Twitter)':friends_count,'Listed(Twitter)':listed_count,
                   'Gender':gender,'Handle':'Twitter'}]
            df=sqlContext.createDataFrame([d])
```

I am getting the below error

ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined after inferring

Comment: Pass the `schema` to  `createDataFrame`

Comment: i assume one of your values is `None`. Hence the schema cannot be inferred. As pissall pointed out it's best to pass the schema